# My camera move script moves backwards on the y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My camera move script moves backwards on the y axis.

Here I leave the script

```
public class PlayerCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;

    public Transform orientation;

    float xRotation;
    float yRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        //Get mouse input 
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

        yRotation += mouseX;

        xRotation += mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        //rotate cam and orientation 
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
        orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    }
}
```

I havent tried anything yet

I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem, it can be simple and I'm sorry, I'm new to programming

Answer (score 0):

If by

> moves backwards on the y axis

You mean that your camera moves up when your mouses goes down and vice versa.
Then why not just multiply the `mouseY` variable by -1 ?
Something like this:

```
float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY * -1;
```

If your problem is something different, then give more details please.